# How to insert multiple values in DB Row read images from folder directory and insert them

Tags: php, mysql, insert, directory

Hi guys i have a nice working PHP script which reads the image files in a directory on my server and insert the imagepath in database. It is working fine but i need to insert more values not only the imagepath also a category and a name but i cant figure out how to make the query work the right way it only iserts the image itself.
I want to insert the whole path instead of only the image with extension and 2 other values like name and category.

Here is the PHP script

```
<?php





$server = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'password';
$dbname = 'dbname';

$connect = mysql_connect($server,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname,$connect);





$path = "folder/subfolder/";
$files = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string',array_map('basename',array_filter(glob("{$path}*.*"),'is_file')));
if(empty($files)){
    echo "There were no matching files to insert into the database.";
} else {    
    $query = "INSERT INTO name (picurl) VALUES ('" . implode("'),('",$files) . "')";
    if(!mysql_query($query)){
        echo "There was a problem inserting the data.";
        trigger_error("Query failed: $query<br />Error: " . mysql_error());
    } else {
        echo "The data was inserted successfully.";
    }
}?>
```

What i need is something like that in the query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO gbpics (picname, picacat, picurl) VALUES ('" . implode("'),('",$files) . "')";
```

And replace the image with extension with the whole part plus the image and extension.
Any Ideas?

Some help would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out here is the solution script:

```
<?php





$server = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'password';
$dbname = 'dbname';

$connect = mysql_connect($server,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname,$connect);





$path = "folder/subfolder/";
$files = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string',array_filter(glob("{$path}*.*"),'is_file'));
if(empty($files)){
    echo "There were no matching files to insert into the database.";
} else {    
    $insertValues = array();
foreach($files as $file)
{
    $insertValues[] = "('value1', 'value2', '{$file}')";
}$query = "INSERT INTO `name` (`picname`, `piccat`, `picurl`) VALUES " . implode(', ', $insertValues);
    if(!mysql_query($query)){
        echo "There was a problem inserting the data.";
        trigger_error("Query failed: $query<br />Error: " . mysql_error());
    } else {
        echo "The data was inserted successfully.";
    }
}?>
```

Comment: Mark this as answered.